# Proxy a secure https to untrusted https site

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy

So i want to setup a payment server with hibiscus (https://www.willuhn.de/products/hibiscus-server/)
and make the connection encrypted with a trusted certificate.
Hibiscus is basically a java servlet which creates a own self
signed ssl certificate, which acording to the author can not be 
replaced with another ssl certificate because the private key is
used to encrypt other things.

So my idea is: Setup nginx with a proxy from port 443 to hibiscuses port
8080, tell nginx to trust the certificate of hibiscus and encrypt 
nginx's 443 with a letsencrypt cert.
nginx would need to unpack the secure content form hibiscus and then
repack it as its own content right?

Does anyone now if this is possible and how?

All help is much appreciated

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am currently running into the same problem ...

Comment: Well, i finally figured out how to give a lets encrypt cert to the insecure service. So i only avoided the problem, sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's not secure. Self signed certificate is not trusted by all of the browsers since the certificate is not signed by any trusted CA, which means, user may suffer from a man-in-the-middle attack. Consider what will happen if I also make a payment server and publish my self signed certificate? User agent can not distinguish which one is real at all.

Comment: Yes thank you. I appears i did not make myself clear. I want to put the payment server behind nginx, in order to make it secure

Comment: @JonasKreusch I know what you mean. The connection from a client to your server is secure (here "secure" only means no one can get the plain text because messages have been encrypted), but anyone who can hijack DNS may fake a server. The client will post username and password to it. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8110/what-are-the-risks-of-self-signing-a-certificate-for-ssl

Comment: Thanks. and sorry for the confusion. For the nginx i want to use letsencrypt in order to make it secure.